# R: ggplot changes order of label

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm facing some problems with ggplot. What I want to do is to plot a normal boxplot graphic and below some tables.

Here I define the values of the tables as a .df:

```
lab.df<-data.frame(lab1=c("0-12.9","13.0-19.2","19.3-23.2","23.3-26.3","26.4-29.8","29.9-33","33.1-36.5","36.6-40.8","40.9-46.2","46.3-100"),
lab2=c("7.80","16.62","21.29","24.71","28.12","31.40","34.80","38.60","43.22","53.77"),
lab3=c("58.63","46.03","46.68","48.84","51.92","54.11","56.50","59.71","62.41","68.33"))
```

And here I create and save the table nr. 2:

```
df.table2 <- ggplot(lab.df, aes(x = lab2, y = 0,
                                label = lab2)) +
  geom_text(size = 5, colour = "black") + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=NULL, name = "Mittelwert Parteistärke (%)")+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), legend.position = "none",
        panel.border = element_blank(), axis.text.x =  element_blank(),
        axis.ticks =  element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 2.9))
```

Now, when I use the table in my ggplot with grid.arrange, the order of the values changes. The same happens when I plot the table with

```
plot(df.table2)
```

The values change from "
**7.80**,16.62,21.29,24.71,28.12,31.40,34.80,38.60,43.22,53.77"
to 
"16.62,21.29,24.71,28.12,31.40,34.80,38.60,43.22,53.77, **7.80**"

No matter how I change the order, 7.80 is always at the end instead of at the beginning. What am I overseeing? Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want these numbers to be `factors` instead of `numerics`? The easiest thing to fix your problem is to just convert to `numerics`

```
lab.df$lab2 <- as.numeric(as.character(lab.df$lab2))
```

If you really need to have factors, you need to specify the desired order. Otherwise the order is just alphabetical and 7.8 comes after 53.77.

```
lab.df$lab2 <- factor(lab.df$lab2, levels=lab.df$lab2)
```

Comment: If I use factors, the numbers in the table arent arranged in the way I like, the space in between the numbers is irregular. But your second solution works phenomenal, thank you very much!